# How to show website preloader only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added a preloader to my website and the preloader animation will play every time the site is visited. I would like it to only play once per visit when going through the domain name - any clicks on the home button on the site or back button in the browser I would like to have the preloader skipped. I would like it to show up any time it is opened in a new tab, or new browser window. I tried adding cookies, but i'm still not connecting it correctly somehow.

Some things to add:
The preloader is made of css @keyframes, (.loader) - its not a .gif.

My site's domain is [jonrouse.com](http://jonrouse.com) for reference.

HTML

```
<div class="preloader">
   <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader-inner"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.preloader {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:99;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).load(function() {
            function Preloader() {
                var preloader = $ ('.loader');
                preloader.delay(1000) .fadeOut (500);
                var preloader = $('.preloader');
                preloader.delay (1500) .slideUp(500);
            }
            Preloader();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any extra info, let me know.

Comment: You said you tried using cookies, but I don't see anything in your javascript to that effect.  Also for the clarity of the readers, can you elaborate on the length of time, or the actions taken, that denote for you when a visit starts and stops?

Comment: The loader exists for one reason:  expensive data processing (images, css, javascript, Etc).  Why do you want to hide the loader?  If the second time a user visits your page, the assets will be cached by the browsers for example.

Comment: @Taplar I've clarified what I consider a visit - and as for the cookies, i'm not certain how to write it out inside of the jQuery. Each time I try, it doesn't appear to do anything (other than break the code, making the preload last forever).

Comment: You've stated when the loader should not show.  You haven't stated when it should show again.  If they leave the site complete and come back, should the loader show again?  If they close the browser, open it again, and go to your website should it show again?  If they are on your page, but open another tab and also go to your page should the loader show again?

Comment: @EleazarEnrique In this instance the loader is being used aesthetically as an intro transition into the site. I do want it to be viewed each time the viewer opens the site from it's domain, like with a new tab or browser.

Comment: In that case I would suggest looking at using `sessionStorage` to hold a variable to tell if the loader should not be shown. (Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).  SessionStorage is tied to the browser window, so the variable will only be available to that window/tab.  Opening another tab/window, or closing the window/tab and opening it again, will cause the variable to be deleted.

Comment: @Taplar Alright, thank you. I'm still pretty new to jQuery, and have difficulty writing the code in. Most of the code I've used thus far have come from plugins. Could you give me any suggestions as to how I would write it in with my current js?

Comment: Just read the link that Taplar provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might use sessionStorage to show the preloader once per visit per tab or window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        function Preloader() {
            var preloader = $ ('.loader');
            preloader.delay(1000) .fadeOut (500);
            var preloader = $('.preloader');
            preloader.delay (1500) .slideUp(500);
        }
        if ( ! sessionStorage.getItem( 'doNotShow' ) ) {
            sessionStorage.setItem( 'doNotShow', 'true' );
            Preloader();
        } else {
           $ ('.loader, .preloader').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow! Excellent. So it's half-worked. I added the code in and it loads the preloader page in on the first visit, but now the consecutive visit just loads the preloader indefinitely, without removing it. Regardless, thank you so much! I appreciate the help. I'll continue to try to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Sorry - I just read your code a little closer. You must have the preloader defaulting to show in your html. Check out the edited code.

Comment: You fixed it! I've been working on it for a few hours, I seriously appreciate it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Great! There's still a little flash of it since the preloader loads before script hides it so maybe go with fadeOut(100

Comment: ) instead of hide() for a smoother "no-show" if you notice it.

Comment: the setItem() method expects a string for the key value, so technically that true should be 'true', e.g.:
            sessionStorage.setItem( 'doNotShow', 'true' );

Comment: Thanks @ErikRühling I updated the answer.