# Show preloader once per visit

Tags: javascript, visitor-pattern

I have been trying to figure this out, I want to show preloader only once per visit. How can I do that?

Current code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {  
        $('#status').fadeOut();  
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
        $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
      })
```

Comment: please clarify your situation a little bit more. is your application a single page web app?

Comment: no, its website and i want to show the preloader once per visit.

Comment: if person will visit any page on my website i want them to "preload" the first page they visit, and if they will visit other page in same session on my website the preloader should not show again.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the **sessionStorage**

```
if ( ! sessionStorage.getItem( 'doNotShow' ) ) {
        sessionStorage.setItem( 'doNotShow', true );
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
    } else {
        $('#preloader').hide();
    }
```

Or take a look on this link [How to show website preloader only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054601/how-to-show-website-preloader-only-once)

Comment: Did you try on the same tab of a browser, SessionStorage will effect or exists only for the same tab, if you try to visit other page in a new tab it's will show the preloader, to fix it use localStorage or other ways.

Comment: yes, tried, preloader was still showing even when page was loaded

Comment: Now, Did you solve this problem ?, If no you should check the data of the sessionStorage/localStorage of your key you set and  see what the output data has. You can tell us about that. We would like to know about the result you get and help you.

Comment: I still have not managed to solve this, how do i find my sessionStorage output data?

Comment: You just simply use console.log(sessionStorage.getItem( 'your key you set' ) ); to showing the information, you can see it in the console of any browser like chrome(open inspector and click console tab). Then you can check what's wrong. In other way if you use chrome browser you can easy to see your sessionStorage data by open inspector mode then click on the application tab you will see the sessionStorage, localStorage... on the left hand side, you can click it(sessionStorage item) to expand  and in there you will see all of sessionStorage do you have.

Comment: Thanks for info, i once again tried your code and its working, but basically i can still see preload div for like 1 second, i want to be hidden completly and not be seen even for splitt second.

Comment: Okay, i think you need to set the div not display at the first time or default it to be not display then you use your code to display it or not display it.

Comment: Yeah sounds great! could you please help me figure this out?
https://jsfiddle.net/wbd35j3L/2/

Comment: Okay, i will take a look on it after i have a time, but i see a litle bit of you code, i did not understand what you need i will check it when i have a time sorry about it.

Comment: Could you please modify my code to make it how you suggested. (default do not display) but for first time display it.

Comment: Okay, please take a look on this https://jsfiddle.net/wbd35j3L/21/ if that's you need.

Comment: still not working properly take a look in action https://uos4m72uukq3mor9-29810030.shopifypreview.com

Answer (score 0):

No cookie whether session or persistent will provide a reliable solution to this problem. The only way I can see doing this properly would be to record the ip address of the visitor and check to see if that record matches one in a table:

- If it doesn't, load the preloader.
- If it does, don't load the preloader.

The only possible problem to this is people periodically clear the temp website data they collect so I would implement a timed record system and set it to a reasonable value like 30 days so if they haven't visited your site in 30 days we will presume they have cleared their cache and they will get the preloader, that would change the criteria to;

- If visitor is new, load preloader
- If visitor is old but less than 30 days, don't load preloader
- If visitor is old and more than 30 days, delete record, create new record, load
  preloader

Code example below;

**#1: Detect IP**

```
<?php
function myIp() {
$client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
$ip = $client;
}
elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
$ip = $forward;
}
else
{
$ip = $remote;
}
return $ip;
}
$my_ip = myIp();
global $my_ip;
?>
```

**#2: Operations**

```
<?php
// Set preloader status
$play_preloader = "no";

// Check visitor ip records for current ip
$preloader_one = "select ip from preloader where ip='$my_ip'";
$connect_preloader_one = mysqli_query($con, $preloader_one);
$rows_preloader_one = mysqli_num_rows($connect_preloader_one);

// If no record exists, create a new one
if ($rows_preloader_one == 0) {
$preloader_insert = mysqli_prepare($con, "insert into preloader (ip) values (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($preloader_insert, "s", $my_ip);
mysqli_stmt_execute($preloader_insert);
$play_preloader = "yes";

// If records exist, find records older than 30 days
} else {
$preloader_two = "select ip,date from preloader where ip='$my_ip' and date < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
$connect_preloader_two = mysqli_query($con, $preloader_two);

// If records older than 30 days found
$rows_preloader_two = mysqli_num_rows($connect_preloader_two);
if ($rows_preloader_two > 0) {
// Delete old records
$preloader_delete = "delete from preloader where ip='$my_ip' and date < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
$preloader_delete_query = mysqli_query($con, $preloader_delete);
// Add new record
$preloader_insert = mysqli_prepare($con, "insert into preloader (ip) values (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($preloader_insert, "s", $my_ip);
mysqli_stmt_execute($preloader_insert);
$play_preloader = "yes";
// If records exist but no records are older than 1 month
} else {
$play_preloader = "no";
}
}

// Preloader
if ($play_preloader == "yes") {
$preloader = "
enter you html/js/css code for the preloader here
";
} else {
$preloader = "";
}
?>
```

Now save all the above code in a php file then reference it in your html and then call $preloader;

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include_once ('mypreloader.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $preloader; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code has been tested on a running server and is working.