# How to show preloader only once using jquery cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies

I have preloader, but it showing on each page after opening, plus on each refresh.
How can I show only once per user? Only after loading homepage

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// makes sure the whole site is loaded
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($.cookie('test_status') != '1') {
    // will first fade out the loading animation
    if(  jQuery( '.et-bfb' ).length <= 0 && jQuery( '.et-fb' ).length <= 0  ){ 
        jQuery(".status").fadeOut();
        // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
        jQuery(".preloader").delay(6750).fadeOut("slow");
    }else{
        jQuery(".preloader").css('display','none');
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="preloader  preloader-center">
<img src="#" alt="">
<p>“uhh.. Hi! We didn’t see you there. One second please”</p>
<video autoplay width="896" muted>
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/MakeItMax_Preloader_HD-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show website preloader only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054601/how-to-show-website-preloader-only-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sessionStorage` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function Preloader() {
    var preloader = $('.preloader');
    preloader.show();
    preloader.delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
  }
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem('doNotShow')) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('doNotShow', true);
    Preloader();
  } else {
    $('.preloader').hide();
  }
})
```

Add css:

```
.preloader{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: After applying this code, preloader won't fade and won't load homepage [link]https://makeitmax.mijnonlinedevelopment.nl/

Comment: Try again, you had to at least put the class that you are using.

Comment: It actually works! :D
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have edited it, if it works please accept my answer.